# VBA for web scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am getting Data from Map.. my code is working perfect but its much slower... i know if I scroll data by using MSXML2.XMLHTTP its get faster but i don't know how to used please anyone help me out here is my code

```
Public Sub Gmap_Links()
        
    On Error Resume Next

    GURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Juventus/@24.2736298,54.6553758,11z/data=!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sAAA!3m4!1s0x3e5e31196fe92369:0x5bb8f4b600b8b5db!8m2!3d24.2736!4d54.6554"
        
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate GURL
    
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState <> 4
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"))
           
    For n = 0 To IE.document.getElementsByClassName("section-subheader-header GLOBAL__gm2-subtitle-alt-1").Length - 1
                                       
        If IE.document.getElementsByClassName("section-subheader-header GLOBAL__gm2-subtitle-alt-1").Item(n).innerText = "Web results" Then
            IE.document.getElementsByClassName("section-subheader-header GLOBAL__gm2-subtitle-alt-1").Item(n).ScrollIntoView (False)
        End If
                                    
    Next n
                                
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
                
    Title = "No Title"
    Link1 = "No Link1"
    Link2 = "No Link2"
    Link3 = "No Link3"
                                                    
    Titel = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("section-hero-header-title-title GLOBAL__gm2-headline-5").Item(0).innerText
                                
    Dim iframe As HTMLIFrame
    Dim Str As String
    
    Set iframe = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("section-iframe-iframe").Item(0)
    Str = iframe.contentDocument.Scripts.Item(7).outerHTML
    Link1 = "http" & Split(Split(Str, "x22http")(2), "\x22,")(0)
    Link2 = "http" & Split(Split(Str, "x22http")(3), "\x22,")(0)
    Link3 = "http" & Split(Split(Str, "x22http")(4), "\x22,")(0)
             
    datarw = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Titel
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = Link1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = Link2
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = Link3
            
    IE.Quit
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    
    Set IE = Nothing
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub
```

in this code there Ie.document scroll to down "Web Result" , Scrollintoview.. when I scroll down page itself update Web result.. I want to get data from web result..

how it possible scrolltoview  in MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Comment: You don't `scrollIntoView()` with xmlhttp. It is a method of web browsers. You need to monitor the web traffic when you scroll on the page, via network tab of browser, and see if there are additional xmlhttp (xhr) requests being made that you can replicate to get whatever you are after.

Comment: SIr please I am not a programmer.. please can you help me out for how to replicate iframe inside the website

Comment: If the iframe has a valid src attribute then make an additional xmlhttp request to that. I assume you are trying to convert the above to just using xmlhttp?

Comment: yes Sir I am trying to above code to just using xmlhttp, because in IE browser its take to long time.. also you are asking me for Iframe valide src.. but be frankly I dont know how to check src.. please if you have some time... please run my code and look there... then if you can convert this code to xmlhttp.. xhr replicate... thanks a lot in advance